# How to hide the one-pixel leftover from the taskbar after activating the “Auto-hide the taskbar” option?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Activating the “Auto-hide the taskbar” option from Taskbar properties doesn’t hide it entirely. A single pixel is left sticking out like a sore thumb and I don’t know to make it go away.

When the monitor was connected through DVI, there was an option available in monitor’s settings through which I could move the screen just several pixels left or right, thus making the sticking out pixels invisible. 
After switching to HDMI, however, this option became unavailable
and the roundabout solution stopped working.

[This page](http://nvidia.helpmax.net/en/display/desktop-size-and-position/how-do-i/centre-or-move-my-screen-position/) says that the screen should be adjustable from NVIDIA’s control panel also, but there are no arrows there, which leads me to believe that it too is not applicable to HDMI.

> 1. From the NVIDIA Control Panel **navigation tree** pane, under **Display**,
>    click **Adjust Desktop Size and Position** to open the page.
> 2. Click the image that represents your VGA display.
> 3. Use the arrow keys on the image that appears to adjust your screen position until your desktop/image is no longer cutoff on any side.

- The monitor is LG 23EA63
- Video Adapter is GeForce GTX 285

Comment: the taskbar pops out when you hover over the line with your mouse. if you don't have it, the task-bar won't be able to popup on mouse-over. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Do you just not like seeing that line, or is there another reason you need it gone?

Comment: Just thinking outside the box, but could you make the remaining 1-pixel stripe NOT stick out like a sore thumb by changing its color somehow?

Comment: Would a desktop background in the same color of gray as the pixel be an option for you? That would make the pixel invisible as it blends into the background. Some picture with a gray-ish area in the corner would be an alternative, of course.

Comment: The problem is each of the open windows that’s displayed on Taskbar has its icon’s colour. I was hoping to find a way to at least move the screen left/right, to be fair. It’s just hard to believe that a simple thing like this can be unsolvable.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it go away..

It needs a recognition area so it can spring up when you hover your mouse there.

It is unrelated to how your screen fits your monitor's resolution, unless you are still on an old CRT screen. LCDs ought to be used at 1:1 pixel resolution for best appearance.

You could possibly push your screen into overscan [at some quality loss] but you'd have to find that in the monitor's manual.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, that's how it is supposed to work, you can't remove it.

A quick Google search pointed me to [this software](http://www.aviassin.com/taskbareliminator) that removes the taskbar on a keypress. Worth a try!